# Issue Broadcasting to Socket.io Rooms of A Namespace

Tags: websocket, socket.io

I'm trying to set up a server that can dynamically create many rooms for many namespaces. I'm currently just trying to broadcast to sockets of a room, when a new socket has joined that room.

So far I have been able to broadcast to a specific namespace and my event listeners on the client receives the message. However when I try to broadcast to a room, of a specific namespace, my event listener doesn't receive that message.

I've turned on the Debugger mode and see the `socket.io-client:socket` emitting the event with the right payload and event type. So I am not sure what I am missing since the documentation also seems fairly straightforward. Any help would be much appreciated. Below is my code.

**Server**

```
const colorNs = io.of('/color');

colorNs.on('connection', (socket) => {
  const { id } = socket.handshake.query;
  const { id:connId } = socket.conn; 
  if(id) {
    socket.join(id);
    socket.broadcast.to(id).emit('user:connect', { id: connId });
  }

  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    const { id } = socket.handshake.query;
    const { id:connId } = socket.conn; 
    socket.broadcast.to(id).emit('user:disconnect', { id: connId });   
  });
});
```

**Client**

```
const socket = io('/color?id="123"');
socket.on('user:connect', () => console.log('data', data));
```

**Client - Debug Trace**

```
socket.io-parser decoded 2/color,["user:connect",{"id":"IZTTPidF121JCzf9AAAO"}] as {"type":2,"nsp":"/color","data":["user:connect",{"id":"IZTTPidF121JCzf9AAAO"}]} +1ms
browser.js:133
socket.io-client:socket emitting event ["user:connect",{"id":"IZTTPidF121JCzf9AAAO"}] +3ms
```